# .htaccess Url Rewrite Hashtag by Value

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make a url rewrite to a page, where it should find a hashtag.

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^/posts/hashtag/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?url=posts&hashtag=$1
```

But this way does not seem to work.
e.g. if the value $1 is funny, the output should be domain.com/posts/hashtag/funny but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this, when you put url `domain.com/posts/hashtag/funny` in your browser it will rewritten to `index.php?url=posts&hashtag=$1` internally.

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^posts/hashtag/([\w-]+)$ index.php?url=posts&hashtag=$1 [QSA,L]
```